# Smoothing of Edges of an Image

Tags: matlab, gradient, smoothing

I have a code generated Image with sharp edges. The change in intensity (gradient) of the edges needs to be reduced so as to give a continuous change in color over the region.

I applied averaging and gaussian low pass filter in MATLAB but it only blurs the image. The requirement is for a sharp image with continuous color change.

Can someone suggest a suitable method for the same?
Thanks in advance.

Example image:

[image]

Comment: what about bluring and then setting all pixels which are of no color in the input image back?

Comment: Basically blurring causes the image to lose its sharpness, hence the quality reduces. What would be preferable is to introduce a continuous change in the color of image,where they are present.

Comment: A continuous change in color means less sharpness. I do not see the difference in blurring and make color changes continuous...

Comment: I think what the OP wants is to blur only within pixels that are non-edges.  As such, find all of the edges / contours in the image, blur the image then replace those pixels that are edges with the original colours.... that's something I'd try.

Comment: That seems like a possible solution. Thanks rayryeng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use non-local means (NLM) or anisotropic diffusion.  NLM is the best for preserving both edges and detail in flat/textured regions.

There are several implementations on MATLAB Central:

- [Non-Local Means Filter](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13176-non-local-means-filter) by Jose Vicente Manjon-Herrera
- [Toolbox Non-Local Means](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13619-toolbox-non-local-means) by Gabriel Peyre
- [Fast Non-Local Means 1D, 2D Color and 3D](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27395-fast-non-local-means-1d--2d-color-and-3d) by Dirk-Jan Kroon

There are many more.